# getting key value pairs out of NSDictionary from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, for-in-loop

I'm a little new to all this and I'm having trouble getting information out of an incoming JSON NSDistionary. Heres the dictionary:

[image]

As a first step I'm trying to retrieve the address sections postcode, here's the code:

```
               for (NSString *address in jsonData [@"address"][@"postcode"]) {
                         NSLog(@"address is ===> %@", address);
                   }
```

However when I run this i am receiving an NSException error:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79e4daf0'

Any help with this would be very much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shown your JSON file contain an array of 3 objects, we first convert data to array.
Then you have to access dictionary by using

1.valueForKeyPath@"dictionarykey1.dictionarykey2".

2.objectForKey@"dictionarykey1".

```
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    NSArray *Response=(NSArray*)[responseObject copy];

    NSString * Address=[Response[0] valueForKeyPath:@"address.postcode"];
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mohamed that fixed it :-)